# A copy of a list is altered on operations on the original list

Tags: python, object, copy, nested-lists

I was writing a snippet to find the determinant of a matrix. The matrix is represented as a nested list like,

```
[[2,3],[5,6]]
```

where the members of the outer list are the rows and that of the inner are the columns.

In a step where the matrix has to be expanded to a simpler one by removing a few elements, I had to save a backup of the original list to another list 'bak' to use it in subsequent expansions.

But after the first expansion step, when i tried to restore the value of the original list from 'bak', it seems the operation on the original list is reflected on 'bak' also.

```
def determinant(matrix):
        if len(matrix)==2:
                det = matrix[0][0]*matrix[1][1]-matrix[1][0]*matrix[0][1]
        if len(matrix)>2:
                flag=0
                bak=[]
                for x in matrix:
                        bak.append(x)
                dump=[]

                for ind,x in enumerate(matrix):
                        matrix.pop(ind)
                        for n,y in enumerate(matrix):
                                matrix[n].pop(ind)

                        dump.append(matrix)
                        print "bak",bak
                        matrix=bak

matrix=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
determinant(matrix)
```

On printing 'bak' the output was [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6], [8, 9]] where it was supposed to be [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

Please help me out if I oversaw any concepts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only storing references to the original list. You want to create *copies* instead:

```
bak.append(x[:])
```

or

```
bak.append(list(x))
```

The `[:]` syntax creates a new list from a slice from the first to the last element of the original list.

Comment: bak.append(x[:]) worked perfect, now i get the desired output, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

(You seem like you're in way over your head. Why do you have all these global variables? Get a handle on how functions work properly, first, before you try to do something like this.)

Because it's not really a copy. `bak` is a separate list-of-lists from `matrix`, but it contains all the same lists that `matrix` does.

Furthermore, each time through the outer loop, you would be "restoring" `matrix` from `bak`... but not by making a copy, just aliasing it! Thus on the second time through the loop, you end up letting `matrix` name the same list-of-lists that `bak` does, and now the intended "backup" purpose is defeated.

The entire approach to this is wrong, though. **Stop trying to "make a copy and then modify it repeatedly", and start "repeatedly making modified versions"**.

And quit trying to tell Python how to put together lists. It knows how.

The code becomes much simpler when we separate out the small tasks into their own functions. First, let's make a function that gives us a list with everything except the specified element:

```
def all_except(a_list, index):
    return a_list[:index] + a_list[index + 1:]
```

That lets us easily make a function that gives us a matrix with everything except the indicated row and column - by asking for "a copy of the row without the specified column, for each row except the specified one":

```
def submatrix(matrix, r, c):
    return [all_except(row, c) for row in all_except(matrix, r)]
    # Alternatively:
    # return [all_except(row, c) for i, row in enumerate(matrix) if i != r]
```

And now we can actually do the recursion. There's no need to actually build the list of minors.

```
def determinant(matrix):
    if len(matrix) < 2: raise ValueError

    if len(matrix) == 2:
        return matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1] - matrix[1][0] * matrix[0][1]

    return sum(
        column * (-1 ** r + c) * determinant(submatrix(matrix, r, c))
        for r, row in matrix
        for c, column in row
    )
```